# How would you edit the properties of an exe file?

Tags: lua, exe

Ive been attempting to figure out how I would edit the properties/details of a exe file.
Can someone help on how to do that?

My program is written in lua, by the way.

Comment: Which details.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to editing metadata, like icon and internal name, you could try using [Angus Johnson's Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

The language you used to create the `.exe` shouldn't matter.